# Using COUNT() in WHERE Clause

Tags: sql-server, count

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT     C.LINKED_TABLE_ID AS CLIENT_DIWOR, I.STATUS AS AML_STATUS, dbo.CLIENT_MASTER.CLIENTCODE
FROM         AML_INFORMATION AS I INNER JOIN
                dbo.COMM_ENTRY AS C ON C.NAME_ID = I.CONTACT_ID AND C.TABLE_ID = 'C' AND C.PRIMARY_FLAG = 'Y' INNER JOIN
                dbo.CLIENT_MASTER ON C.LINKED_TABLE_ID = dbo.CLIENT_MASTER.DIWOR
WHERE I.CONTACT_ID = 234
    AND I.[STATUS] = 'CC'
    AND (CLIENT_MASTER.DIWOR = I.CONTACT_ID)
    AND (CLIENT_MASTER.POSTING_STATUS <> '')
    AND ((SELECT COUNT(CONTACT_ID) FROM AML_ID_DOCUMENT GROUP BY CONTACT_ID HAVING CONTACT_ID = 234) >1)
```

If I run this it returns 0 records, however if I remove the last AND statement `AND ((SELECT COUNT(CONTACT_ID) FROM AML_ID_DOCUMENT GROUP BY CONTACT_ID HAVING CONTACT_ID = 234) >1)` it returns the records I would expect.

Is it possible to use a COUNT() in this way?  Incidentally, the COUNT() in this example returns 2 records and if I include it in the SELECT statement I also get 0 records returned.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldnt your query haver a FROM clause somewhere?

Comment: Are you looking for the existence of the contact or are you looking for the existence of the contact where it's used more than once.

Comment: Re-added the FROM clause, missed it somehow during copy & paste

Comment: @TEEKAY I am looking for the existence of the CONTACT_ID where it exists more than once.

Comment: @vasja/bummi Running SELECT COUNT(CONTACT_ID) FROM AML_ID_DOCUMENT GROUP BY CONTACT_ID HAVING CONTACT_ID = 234 in isolation returns "2" which is correct. So should having this as part of the where clause of the "main" query not evaluate correctly?

Comment: I think your GROUP BY is then making the count 1 ? Try removing the group by in your subquery.

Comment: I tried your AND HAVING GROUP part, it works on my system, I did an edit on my prior answer ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your showed Script should never return anything ...
your having part could look this way

```
   and (Select Count(*) from AML_ID_DOCUMENT  where CONTACT_ID =I.CONTACT_ID)>1
```

though ist should work as it is...

Comment: I want to return records from AML_INFORMATION where there are a minimum of 2 records (for a given contact) in AML_ID_DOCUMENT.

Comment: I'm not sure what you amended in this script (can't recall the original) but it appears to have done the trick.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

Shouldn't the last part be like this:

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT CONTACT_ID FROM AML_ID_DOCUMENT
      WHERE CONTACT_ID = 234
      GROUP BY CONTACT_ID
      HAVING COUNT(CONTACT_ID)>1)
```

Comment: This evaluates to true and returns the CONTACT_ID when run in isolation but does not work when it forms part of the where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select count(portfolio_id) as porfolioCount 
from engineering_module_tracker_v2 
where r0_approval__category='Cat I' & 'Cat II';
```

Cat means category-wise.